# How can I manage a Windows Server 2012 R2 Failover Cluster from a Windows 7 client?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-cluster

The [Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887) seem to only support managing Windows Server 2008 and 2008 R2 servers. Is there a tool that can be installed on a Windows 7 client to manage a Windows Server 2012 R2 server? Specifically I want to use the Failover Cluster Manager.

If I try to connect to a 2012 R2 cluster, I get the following error:

```
The cluster to which you are attempting to connect is not a version of the 
cluster supported by this version of Failover Cluster Manager.
```

I assume I may be limited to accessing the server via Remote Desktop?

Comment: ...Windows 8 uses the same version of RSAT as Server 2012, so that's another way.  If you can stomach Windows 8, of course.

Comment: Install a mix of HyperV boxes on 2008 and 2012 and watch the tools for each refuse to play with the other.  This seems to be a common MS thing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, this can't be done. RSAT is designed for its version of windows paired with its version of server OS.

Comment: Um, what?  Who does that?  My Android doesn't specifically say all the things it can't do either, which is fine... because when I want to set someone on fire, I look for tools that specifically say they can do what I want, such as my flamethrower.

Comment: @HopelessN00b I think it would be relatively easy to mention the compatibility of their tool versions. I have ran into this type of thing a few times with Microsoft. BTW, I'd pay good money for a flamethrower app.

Comment: They **do** do that. Windows 7 RSAT works on Windows 7, and Server 2008 R2. That's what it's compatible with. Use it with anything else at your own peril/risk.